# UITableView with Pages that contain X rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to achieve a **UITableView** that can be scrolled horizontally by page, each page containing 10 rows (every row has the same height)

I know **UITableView** extends **UIScrollView** but **pagingEnaled** + **contentSize** doesn't seem to do the trick so I'm stuck

Basically I have a **UITableView** with 100 rows and I'd like to have pages of 10 that I can scroll horizontally, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions:

Either you go with the newly added in iOS6 [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) (but then you need to set as a minimum target for your app iOS6)

or you add 3 UITableViews inside a UIScrollView next to each other and move the first or last UITableView when a new page is displayed to the UIScrollView.

There is a ready to use implementation for this here: https://github.com/arconsis/ARTableViewPager

Comment: I just read about UICollectionView and seems like a nice deal, however I'm confused as it seems that I'd need to create multiple UITablewViews on different sections and scroll the UICollectionView manually? How is this different from using the UIScrollView + UITablewView approach from ARTableViewPager? Is there a way to have UICollectionView display X rows in the first column and then the next and so on?